# Google Cloud SDK - Automate gcloud auth login web flow

Tags: authentication, automation, google-oauth, remote-server, gcloud

After I install google cloud sdk, when I run '`gcloud auth login`', it provides me a link to copy paste into my browser to obtain new credentials and authenticate my account.

However, I want to setup and use gcloud on a remote machine where a user will not be available to copy paste the link generated in the browser and paste the resultant verification code back into the terminal. How do I automate this without user intervention?

My account is an end user account i.e. not a service account.

Is there any other alternative to do this whereby I can pre-authenticate my account using the generated link to use in the browser on my local machine and then use the same configuration on the remote machine?

Thanks in advance!

**Update based on Vilas's comments:**

I am pretty sure I am using the right json key file because I am not modifying the name/contents after downloading it from the google developers console. I tried removing account@gmail.com from the above command. But still getting the same error

```
ERROR: (gcloud.auth.activate-service-account) The .json key file is not in a valid format. Your current active account [account@gmail.com] does not have any valid credentials.Please run:

  $ gcloud auth login

to obtain new credentials, or if you have already logged in with a
different account:

  $ gcloud config set account ACCOUNT

to select an already authenticated account to use.

Your current active account [account@company.com] does not have any valid credentials
Please run:

  $ gcloud auth login

to obtain new credentials, or if you have already logged in with a
different account:

  $ gcloud config set account ACCOUNT

to select an already authenticated account to use.
```

Comment: Why can't you create a service account for your project?

Comment: Created a service account and downloaded the json key file. I then ran this command - $gcloud auth activate-service-account account@gmail.com --key-file client-service-account-client-2.json. Got the error: ERROR: (gcloud.auth.activate-service-account) The .json key file is not in a valid format.

Comment: Are you sure you are using the right json key file? Additionally, you do not need to provide the account@gmail.com when you provide the json key file. They key file has the account in it.

Comment: Please check my question description. Updated it with the outcome of your suggestions.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's a quick check to see if you have the right --key-file .json file: it must contain a **client_email** field/attribute.

Comment: My .json file does not have the client_email field in it. Here are the contents of the .json file - {"installed":{"client_id":"xxxxxxx-yyyyyyy.apps.googleusercontent.com","project_id":"dev","auth_uri":"https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth","token_uri":"https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token","auth_provider_x509_cert_url":"https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v1/certs"}}

Comment: What could be a possible workaround? The generation of the .json file is beyond my control since I am downloading this file from the Google developers console!

Answer (score 0):

I just had the same issue, the key was not displaying any email address, so I generated a new key in the Developers Console for the service account and it was created with the email address.